# How can I import another file from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to import a file to /components/login/index from /actions/login but I am getting an error:

Failed to compile.

./src/components/login/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './actions/login' in 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\AppName\src\components\login'

This is my file stream

[image]

and I want to import here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a named export, so:

```
export Login .........
```

or an export default, so:

```
export default Login;
```

The way you're importing Login component suggests you are not importing Login component as default.

Have you tried below?

```
import Login from './actions/login';
```

Addition based on the comment:

`Components` folder is an empty folder. To reach `actions` folder, your import should be like below:

```
import Login from '../../actions/login';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried, but it didn't. Could the problem be './actions/login'?

Comment: @AlperenARICI I think that's the right direction. From the screenshot, I see that components folder is empty. So you need to go one level up of 'components' folder to get to the 'actions' folder. So something like: '../../actions/login' in the component.

Comment: I moved actions folder to components and done it. Thank you.